# If $f\in L^{\infty}$ with finite support and $g\in H^{s}$ and $g\geq 0$, then why $fg\notin H^{s}$ in general?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $f\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+)$ with support in an open interval $(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ ($a,b$ finite) and $g\in H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^+)$ for some $s\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, with $g$ a positive function (i.e. $g\geq 0$). In other words,

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} (1+x^2)^{s}\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ixt}g(t )dt\right|^2dx < \infty $$

I am trying to understand why $fg\notin H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^+)$ in general. Indeed, isn't it true that

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} (1+x^2)^{s}\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ixt}f(t)g(t )dt\right|^2dx < |f|_{L^{\infty}} |g|_{H^{s}}^2 < \infty $$

I am sure there is something I am missing, because if $fg$ is discontinuous then it will not belong to $H^{s}$ for $s\geq 1/2$. But I don't see which part of the previous inequality is incorrect.

Comment: To get the $L^{\infty}$ norm of $f$ out, you must put the absolute values inside the integral. But then this means you get $\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}\|g\|_{L^1}$ (this should be squared). You can’t integrate this over $x$ anymore; the result will be infinite (i.e using a crude $L^{\infty}$ bound on $f$ means you’re ignoring all the cancellations present in the Fourier transform’s definition). Also, looks like you’re missing squares and square roots consistently. Also, note that in general, for $g$ merely in $L^2$, the Fourier transform isn’t defined directly via an integral.

Comment: Your formula for the $H^s$ norm is wrong. It should be $L^2$ based:

$$\|g\|_{H^s}^2 :=\int_{0}^{\infty} (1+x^2)^{s}\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ixt}g(t )dt\right|^2dx < \infty.$$

Comment: I see yes ... So my problem is that I basically wrote $e^{-ixt}g(t)f(t)\leq |f|_{L^{\infty}}e^{-ixt}g(t)$ for $g\geq 0$, which is false because of the complex exponential. Thank's! I also edited the norms in my question.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, you should write this as the answer

Comment: I want to add for completeness that this answers also another question I had: do we have $L^{\infty} \subset H^{s}$ with $s<\frac{1}{2}$ for bounded intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ ? And the answer is no, because we can not just throw away the $L^{\infty}$ norm. So in general, we do not have that $L^{\infty}$ is a subset of $H^{s}$ if $s\neq 0$.

Comment: The heuristic you should always have in mind is that the $s$ is a regularity (or differentiability parameter). E.g. for $k$ a positive integer, being in $H^k$ means that your distributional derivatives of order up to $k$ lie in $L^2$, with the non-integer regularity case being a generalisation of this. This heuristic explains why $L^\infty \not \subset H^s$ for $s > 0$, since $L^\infty$ functions don't need to have any kind of spatial regularity. It also explains why the product of $f$ and $g$ is at best $L^\infty$ in general (e.g. in the integer case think of the product rule).

Comment: I see yes, thank you for this detailed answer!